# How can I integrate Adyen on my website

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, adyen

As I can integrate Adyen API into my website, the checkout documentation does not seem very specific to me. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the GitHub examples: [Adyen GitHub](https://github.com/Adyen)
and the API reference will give you an idea of how the request and response looks like: [Here](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/v32/overview)

Comment: Adyen documentation seems (for me) difficult to understand :( ... but I'll take a look  Thanks Michael

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is a lot simpler these days:

1. Access the Adyen Customer Area (with your [Adyen account](https://www.adyen.com/signup)) and setup the keys:
   [API key](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/api-credentials#generate-your-api-key): required to access the Adyen platform
   [Client Key](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/client-side-authentication): required to render client components
   [Merchant Account](https://docs.adyen.com/account/account-structure): merchant identifier
   [HMAC Key](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks/verify-hmac-signatures): required to perform webhook authentication
2. Setup a [webhook](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks): this is necessary to receive the final confirmation of each payment transaction.
3. In the Adyen Customer Area do not forget to update the **Allowed Origin** list: include the URL(s) of the web application which will host the Adyen checkout. This is **a very important step** and often overlooked during the setup.
4. Integrate the Web [Drop-in](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in) (*): given the nature of the project (web site) the most convenient approach is to use the Web Drop-in which renders the payment methods available to the shopper (ie based on country and other factors) and takes care of the payment execution.
5. Implement the Webhook (*) that will receive the payment confirmation from the Adyen server.

(*) Adyen supports a variety of languages and frameworks. Head to [Adyen Examples](https://github.com/adyen-examples) repositories and checkout the example that suits your need (ie Python with Flask, Java with Spring, .Net core, etc..).

Every example includes the instructions on how to setup and run the demo as well as the code needed to integrate the Drop-in and the webhook.