# Using Adyen from a SPA

Tags: single-page-application, payment, adyen

We are building a marketplace using angular and we want to integrate Adyen payments. Googling for 'Adyen angular' or 'Adyen SPA' or even 'Adyen react' doesn't bring any useful results. NO results whatsoever.

Therefore I am left wondering, why the whole world (including Adyen docs) is not talking about integrating Adyen into a SPA.

It doesn't seem to be more vulnerable to network security attacks to me. At least I can't think of any reasons for that.

Please help me to understand, what I am missing out.

Comment: I'm currently on a project where we use Adyen from a SPA (React). One of the reasons you can't find any information regarding this is probably because it's not that different from using Adyen in a multiple page application. Surely we had to change some places where initialization were made due to server side rendering and Ayden's script injecting iframes, but other than that it was pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I overestimated Adyen popularity and in reality, the truth is that it is just not popular enough to have gotten attention from SPA community. :(

Answer (score 5):

As madesch mentioned, integrating in a SPA shouldn't be too far from other kinds of integrations. Are you having issues with something in particular?

Here can see an integration with [Vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-adyen-dropin-4j4ut), one with [React](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-adyen-dropin-56vlt) and even one with [React Hooks](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-adyen-dropin-q8lxc).

The card fields are not being loaded because I'm not using a real `originKey`, but it should give you an idea about how to do the integration.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like `originKey` is [deprecated](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/how-to-get-an-origin-key), the current recommendation is to use [Web DropIn](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in). But this requires using a server component, as you don't want to expose your API key, right?

So if you don't want to use a deprecated API, you must always add a server component to your stack. A pure SPA does not seem to be possible using current APIs, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There are now few options available:

- [Angular](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-angular-online-payments) support
- [Vue](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-vue-online-payments) support
- [React](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-react-online-payments) support

All examples are based on the [Web Drop-in](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-react-online-payments) approach which renders a checkout component with the supported/requested payment methods.

A basic explanation of the workflow is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71678556/9095551).